# Htaccess Image redirect to page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect in `.htaccess` these kind of URLs:

```
example.com/wp-content/uploads/summer-fashion-1680x1050.jpg
```

to these kind of posts?

```
example.com/summer-fashion
```

Comment: it is only one image or group of images?

Comment: group of images

Comment: Is `/wp-content/uploads/summer-fashion-1680x1050.jpg` an actual image? Are you intending to display this image on the `/summer-fashion` "page"? This question sounds a lot like this other recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510662/htaccess-redirection-for-image-link

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following in `.htaccess`, *before* the existing WordPress (front controller) directives:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(\w+)-\d{2,4}x\d{2,4}\.jpg$ /$1 [R,L]
```

However, you will naturally get problems if you are trying to display `/wp-content/uploads/summer-fashion-1680x1050.jpg` on the page itself (which I suspect you are trying to do?), since this request will also be caught by the above directive and you'll get an infinite loop.

One way to prevent this "loop" is to append an additional query string onto the end of the image URL when it is used in-page and modify the above directive to only redirect when that query string is not present on the URL. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^noredirect=1$
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(\w+)-\d{2,4}x\d{2,4}\.jpg$ /$1 [R,L]
```

And link to your image like this:

```
<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/summer-fashion-1680x1050.jpg?noredirect=1" alt="">
```

However, this could be troublesome to maintain and is not hidden from the user (if that is the intention) - so can easily be circumvented. It could also be problematic for SEO (image search - if that is a convern), unless you take additional measures to prevent the URL param from being indexed.

Another option is to check the HTTP `Referer` header and only redirect if the `Referer` is *not* your site. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example\.com
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(\w+)-\d{2,4}x\d{2,4}\.jpg$ /$1 [R,L]
```

However, this is also problematic and not 100% reliable. Browsers might not send a `Referer` header and the `Referer` can be faked.